# How do you open a pdf file in python Juypterlab? I want to transform the data, but I can't get the file to open?

Tags: python, pdf, dataset, transformation, azure-mapping-data-flow

I need to convert data from a pdf file and transform it into a cleaned excel file. I need to take a dataset that is messy and clean it up. The issue is that it's a pdf file and I can't figure out what the code would be to open it.

I'm unable to get the file to open in Jupyterlab to even start to figure out how to clean the dataset. Also, feel free to help with any tip suggestions of how to clean a dataset in python.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.Popen([path/to/file],shell=True)
```